# c# assigning a random result from an array to a variable returns outofrange error

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm trying to create a program that generates random numbers; indexes a table; stores the results in some lists; then shows the results from the lists at a later point.  I have a int variable called FreqMod which I'm trying to assign the random result from an array called FrequencyModifiers[].  This is throwing a runtime error "OutOfRange" as if it's getting a null value.  But I don't see how.  Let me see if I can post all the relevant code:

```
int TheHour = 0, TheMinute = 0, PlaceHolder = 0, FreqMod = 0;
int[] FrequencyModifier =
                    {
                        -3, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6
                    };// int array FrequencyModifier

     DiceResult = 0;
     DiceResult = RollDice.TwoD6();

     FreqMod = FrequencyModifier[DiceResult - 1];
```

This will be a modifier added to the results of later dice rolls.

tried this after some research and still no joy:

```
int[] FrequencyModifier =
                    {
                        -3, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6
                    } ;// int array FrequencyModifier

                    FrequencyModifier = new int[11];

                    DiceResult = 0;
                    DiceResult = RollDice.TwoD6();

                    FreqMod = FrequencyModifier[DiceResult - 1];
```

from a class called dice, of which RollDice is an object:

```
 public int TwoD6()
            {
                diceresult = 0;
                numdice = 2;
                for(int i = 1; i <= numdice; i++)
                {
                    dieresult = 0;
                    lowest = 1;
                    highest = 6;
                    diceresult = diceresult + (1 + Rolldie.Next(lowest-1, highest));
                }
                return diceresult;
```

DiceResult should be the random number returned from the method RollDice.TwoD6.
I am trying to use it to assign the corresponding number from the array to FreqMod.  So that if the random number returned is 3, then it would assign -2.

Before Christmas it had been almost 20 years since I looked at C and C++; I'm now trying to learn C#.

Comment: What are DiceResult and RollDice.TwoD6()?

Comment: ok, because I'm using 2D6, I realized I need to change the -1 in the assignment to -2.  tested that and now I'm getting different results.  I'm going to try this throughout my code where I know I have made this mistake and see if that helps.

Comment: You seem to set zero to diceresult inside the for loop every iteration. But if that's just a typo here, your row diceresult = diceresult + (1 + Rolldie.Next(lowest-1, highest)); can (at least to my understanding) give maximum value of 13. Your array FrequencyModifier is only 11 long. That would result in out of range exception